# Check for ranges overlapping database side with coalesce

Tags: mysql, range, overlapping, coalesce

I can't figure out how to check on database side if two ranges, that can handle null values (ex. range A: null - null range B: 3 - 10), overlaps.

In this case, those two ranges overlaps because in my code null - null it's equal to -∞ and +∞ so 3 - 10 is inside -∞ - +∞.

The problem is that i need to build a query that returns all the records from my table stock_rule that have a range that overlaps with the stock_rule record that i'm trying to create.

If the count is major than zero then i can't save the record.

I'm trying to achieve that using COALESCE function (MySQL 8.0) in this way:

```
COALESCE(rule.min_price, 0)<=COALESCE(:minPrice, rule.min_price,0) AND 
COALESCE(rule.max_price, 0)<=COALESCE(:minPrice, rule.max_price, 0) AND 
COALESCE(rule.min_price, 0)<=COALESCE(:maxPrice, rule.min_price,0) AND 
COALESCE(rule.max_price, 0)<=COALESCE(:maxPrice, rule.max_price, 0) AND 
COALESCE(:minPrice, 0)>=COALESCE(rule.min_price, :minPrice, 0) AND 
COALESCE(:maxPrice,0)<=COALESCE(rule.min_price, :maxPrice, 0) AND 
COALESCE(:minPrice,0)>=COALESCE(rule.max_price, :minPrice, 0) AND
COALESCE(:maxPrice, 0)<=COALESCE(rule.max_price, :maxPrice, 0)
```

Comment: Can a price be negative?

Comment: @Strawberry no, it can't but unfortunately i can't force minPrice to be 0 to default.

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like this would work...

```
DROP TABLE ranges;

CREATE TABLE ranges
(id seriAL PRIMARY KEY
,range_start INT NULL
,range_end INT NULL
);

INSERT INTO ranges VALUES
(1,NULL,NULL),
(2,3,10),
(3,12,NULL),
(4,NULL,20),
(5,10,11);

  SELECT *
    FROM ranges x
    JOIN ranges y
      ON y.id <> x.id
     AND COALESCE(x.range_start,0) <= y.range_end
     AND COALESCE(x.range_end,(SELECT MAX(range_end) FROM ranges)) >= y.range_start;
+----+-------------+-----------+----+-------------+-----------+
| id | range_start | range_end | id | range_start | range_end |
+----+-------------+-----------+----+-------------+-----------+
|  1 |        NULL |      NULL |  2 |           3 |        10 |
|  4 |        NULL |        20 |  2 |           3 |        10 |
|  5 |          10 |        11 |  2 |           3 |        10 |
|  1 |        NULL |      NULL |  5 |          10 |        11 |
|  2 |           3 |        10 |  5 |          10 |        11 |
|  4 |        NULL |        20 |  5 |          10 |        11 |
+----+-------------+-----------+----+-------------+-----------+


mysql>
```